# How do I use WMI in C#

Tags: c#, wmi

the compiler does not recognize SelectQuery api and ManagementObjectSearcher.  According to what I can see in the online examples, all I need to do is to add

using System.Management

as a namespace

Answer (score 3):

You also need to add a reference in your project to  `System.Management.dll`.

You can see this for any class by looking at the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher.aspx).  Note this:

```
Namespace:  System.Management
Assembly:  System.Management (in System.Management.dll)
```

This means you'll want to add a `using System.Management;` in order to import the namespace, but also that it requires a reference to `System.Management.dll`.